# Parsing JSonObject response by Rest client java

Tags: rest, http-get, json, rest-client

I have written the RestClient to call the rest service and then parse the response. I use this:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
 }
  try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
  return jObj;
```

I m getting response like this :

```
{\"r\":{\"@status\":\"ok\",\"@st\":\"ok\",\"@call_id\":\"8410e\",\"method\":\"notification\",\"notification\":" +
            "{\"@status\":\"true\",\"n\":{\"objects\":{\"@totalClassCount\":\"35\",\"@totalTestCount\":\"0\",\"@totalContentCount\":\"0\"," +
            "\"@totalAssignmentCount\":\"5\",\"@totalOverdueCount\":\"16\",\"@totalCourseCount\":\"97\",\"@lastClassTime\":\"01-01-1753 12:00:00\"," +
            "\"@lastTestTime\":\"01-01-1753 08:00:00\",\"@lastContentTime\":\"09-01-2015 02:52:30\",\"@lastAssgnTime\":\"01-01-1753 08:00:00\"," +
            "\"@lastOverdueTime\":\"01-01-1753 12:00:00\",\"@lastCourseTime\":\"09-01-2015 02:52:30\",\"@lastCommentTime\":\"14-12-2015 03:48:55\"," +
            "\"flag\":\"1\",\"object\":[{\"@type\":\"3\",\"content\":{\"@contentid\":\"137\",\"ntype\":\"1\",\"sime\":\"9 months ago\"," +
            "\"title\":{\"#cdata-section\":\"xlsx icon file\"},\"courseid\":\"95137\",\"sid\":\"1976\",\"subid\":\"0\",\"coursetype\":\"1\",\"contentsize\":" +
            "\"0\",\"csid\":\"2\",\"contenttypeid\":\"6\",\"contentviews\":\"0\",\"totalslides\":\"16\",\"iscreator\":\"0\"}}}]}}}}}
```

Could you please help me how i can parse it?

Thanks,
itin

Answer (score 0):

The code for converting to JSON is not exactly right - Try JSONObject. you can do better as shown below.

```
 if (httpEntity != null) {
           String resultString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity); 
           // parsing JSON and convert String to JSON Object
           JSONObject result = new JSONObject(resultString); 
     return result;
```

Comment: Do you means instead of BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader this code i use tour code of lines rt?

Comment: Yes and then return the jObj. Just added a log or sysout before return to see what is being returned. please accept and upvote if this helps.

Comment: I have done this  if (httpEntity != null) {
                    String resultString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity); 
                    // parsing JSON and convert String to JSON Object
                   JSONObject  jObj = new JSONObject(resultString); 
                } return jObj ,  Result has string but jObj is null.

Comment: Thanks, but story start after this... i got the string which i mentioned above.. now i have to parse it, if it return an object then how i will get the data of perticular keys?

Comment: You have got the answer to what you originally asked so ideally you should have accepted and up-voted my response first. To answer your question JSONObject can be easily read using various getters - read more here http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html